# VS Code search in workspace is only looking in the opened files in editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, search

I used to be able to search for a text in any files in the workspace in the editor in VS Code. Now it only looks for the keyword in the opened files. I don't know how to restore the old settings back. I want to be able to find the keyword in closed files as well as opened files. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am getting this message, "No results found in **open editors**. Review your settings for configured exclusions and check your gitignore files - Open Settings - Learn More"

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utWWh.png)

Comment: Are you sure the `Search Only in Open Editors` button is not disabled?  Click the `...` to open the `files to exclude` input.  Make sure there is nothing listed there and the little open book icon at the end is not enabled.

Answer (score 8):

There is a setting in files options, under the "replace all" button. Disable the open book icon and you'll be able to search closed files as well.

[image]